# In ruby how can i return values from a while loop inside method without closing the method iself ?

Tags: ruby

I want the program to return the values from the loop inside the method, not restarting everytime the method when i call it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a yield statement or a proc to take the value in the loop and do whatever you want with it:

```
def yielder
  i = 5
  while i > 0 do 
    puts i
    i -= 1
    yield i
  end
end

yielder {|i| puts "returning the value of #{i}"  }
```

Comment: so the yield method practically return the values without closinf the method evrytime if i get it ?

Comment: calling 'yield' from the method yields the execution of the code to the block after the method name - so whatever is in between { } - and then afterward, resumes execution of the original method called .

Comment: so when the program arrives at the first yields it exits the values, execute the code after the method, and then restart the execution from the last yield called , if i catch it ?

Comment: Yes, I think you've got the gist of it.

Comment: but i really need the two { } or i can just puts yielder to see the results of the method ?

Comment: You need the block.  Also, the result of a method is the last thing executed or whatever is returned, so 'seeing the results' is a bit ambiguous.  If you want the results of a method, just execute the method and have the results be the last thing returned.  If you want to perform some operation on each iteration of a loop without exiting it, using yield would be one way to do it.  Also, look at this documentation http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Proc.html

Comment: thanks very usefull ;) just one last thing if i want another method that receive the result of the yield of the first one mentioned before ?